# How come Google Play can install APK without user interaction

Tags: android, google-play, android-package-managers

As everyone knows since google play comes as a system app it can get all the permissions and apis which are hidden to a 3rd party applications, it can install apks on background without user interactions(without clicking install).

One of my client needs an official proof saying the same. If you know an official link (maybe in support.google or developer.android) please post it in here.

Comment: There is no way for a third party developer to install an APK without user interaction, it is too much of a security risk. Google can as its there own OS and there own servers but it would be a huge risk to allow any developer to be able to install third party applications without user consent

Comment: thats correct.. but what i want to know is how does the google do the installation with out users interference. like because ... google-play can do that. and heres an official link to proove.. :-)

Comment: There's is no documentation about how they do it because they don't want people to do it. Google do it because its there own OS and they have complete control over it and can at will install and remove anything from anyones device.

Answer (score 5):

To be able to install packages directly an application needs to hold [the `INSTALL_PACKAGES` permission](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/android-4.4.4_r2/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml#L2042-L2047). This permission has a `protectionLevel` of `signature|system`, meaning that the only apps that can hold it have to be either:

- signed by the signing key that signed the firmware, or
- installed on the system partition (e.g., a pre-installed app, an app moved to the system partition via a user who has rooted their device)